# Bernoulli trial and asymptotic analysis

Tags: asymptotics

I want to find such function $p(n)$ in a way that obtaining one succes will be asymptotically-equivalent to obtaining two failures.
I basically want to have something like this:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{{n \choose 1}p(n)(1-p(n))^{n-1}}{{n \choose 2}(1-p(n))^2p(n)^{n-2}}}= $$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{np(n)(1-p(n))^{n-1}}{\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}(1-p(n))^2p(n)^{n-2}}}=...=$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{2(1-p(n))^{n-3}}{(n-1)p(n)^{n-3}} } = 1$$
And now I'm kind of stuck... what do do with $n-1$ in denominator? I could use some hints.

Comment: So you want to find function $p(n)$ s.t. getting $1$ success in $n$ trials with probability of success $p(n)$ is asymptotically the same as getting $2$ failures?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't even need asymptotic here. Just write
$$\frac{2(1 - p(n))^{n - 3}}{(n - 1)p(n)^{n - 3}} = 1$$
and solve w.r.t. $p(n)$:
$$\sqrt[n - 3]{2} (1 - p(n)) = \sqrt[n - 3]{n - 1} p(n)$$
$$p(n) = \frac{\sqrt[n - 3]{2}}{\sqrt[n - 3]{n - 1} - \sqrt[n - 3]{2}}$$
and if we replace $1$ in the first equation with $1 + o(1)$, we get general solution
$$p(n) = \frac{\sqrt[n - 3]{2}}{\sqrt[n - 3]{n - 1} - \sqrt[n - 3]{2} + o(1)}$$